# gnu makefile coding style

Tags: coding-style, makefile, gnu-make

Every time I need to touch a nontrivial makefile it takes time to adjust eyes/brain to the syntax. In attempt to make adaptation smoother I am looking for a good coding style (essentially line breaks and indentation that would increase readability without breaking the code). Has anyone come across a good one?

```
$$(foreach name,$$(BUILDERS_$$(TARGET_TYPE)_ARGS),$$(if $$(filter undefined,$$(origin TARGET_$$(name))),$$(error [$$(TARGET_NAME)] is missing mandatory argument [$$(name)] for the builder [$$(TARGET_TYPE)])))
```

Something like the below but working

```
$$(foreach name,$$(BUILDERS_$$(TARGET_TYPE)_ARGS),
    $$(if $$(filter undefined,$$(origin TARGET_$$(name))),
        $$(error [$$(TARGET_NAME)] is missing mandatory argument [$$(name)] for the builder [$$(TARGET_TYPE)])
    )
)
```

Comment: The example should work if you add backslashes at the ends of the lines.

Comment: @MadScientist - I would accept that as an answer, I like the resulting look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break a function most anywhere you want, but you have to add a backslash before the newline.

The one exception is that whitespace before commas is preserved in some sorts of functions, so be careful when constructing filenames, etc. where adding embedded whitespace might cause issues.

Given your example above, it will work as:

```
$$(foreach name,$$(BUILDERS_$$(TARGET_TYPE)_ARGS),\
    $$(if $$(filter undefined,$$(origin TARGET_$$(name))),\
        $$(error [$$(TARGET_NAME)] is missing mandatory argument [$$(name)] for the builder [$$(TARGET_TYPE)])\
    )\
)
```